# What movement abilities are there?

Tags: destiny-2

So far from the open beta I have had more frustration with the movement system, out of everything else. It seems I have very little in the way of movement options -- it seems that either I can double jump and I can sprint into a slide, but is that it?

With that note I did play Hunter and the Titan so perhaps I'm missing something, but are there more movement abilities, or is that the extent of how I can move in game?

Comment: It's about that and the blink or glide movements from warlock. There's sparrows you'll be able to ride eventually to move quicker (not in beta).

Comment: I mean what else would you like it to have?

Comment: Air dashes, rolls, jetpacks, anything to give me more flexibility. As it stands all I do during fights is double jump around the area madly

Comment: That's about what you've got.. There are rolls with the hunter as an ability, and I *think* titans have jetpack-esque ability, but again, it's fairly limited

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In addition to the below, all classes are able to vault, or pull themselves up, onto ledges and terrain, and of course can sprint and jump. There may be more movement abilities granted by exotic items and/or currently unseen subclass talents in the full game so this list may grow.

*Titan* has a **jetpack** as their jump ability across all subclasses. The jetpack provides an upward thrust when used and lasts a short time. Options to augment the jetpack include more height, more directional control or faster acceleration. The Striker subclass also has a **shoulder charge** which both deals damage and propels you a small distance forwards.

*Warlock* has a **glide** for their jump across as subclasses. The glide continues your momentum and lasts until you land on the ground or deactivate it. The glide differs from the Titan because if you are falling it will only slow your fall, not boost you upwards. Options to augment the glide include more height, more directional control or a burst of speed on use. In place of the more height augment, the Voidwalker subclass has the option to replace the glide with a **blink**, a short range teleport. The Dawnblade subclass has a perk in the top-most passive skill group that gives a **mid-air dash**.

*Hunter* has a **double jump** as well as a **dodge roll** across all subclasses. The double jump may be augmented with a triple jump, higher jump height or better directional control.